# Drawing lines to the correct circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code

```
\def\aes{in*0.75}%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.34mm]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(30:4\aes)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(-90:2.5\aes)$);

  \draw[line width=2pt,gray!60,postaction={draw,black,dashed,line width=1.4pt}] (A) circle (\aeRadiusA);

  \draw[red] (B) circle (\aeRadiusB);
  \draw[blue] (C) circle (\aeRadiusC);

  \coordinate (A1a) at ($(A)+(-20:\aeRadiusA*0.75)$);
  \coordinate (C1a) at ($(C)+(90+20:\aeRadiusC*0.75)$);
  \coordinate (A1b) at ($(A1a)+(3pt,2pt)$);
  \coordinate (C1b) at ($(C1a)+(0pt,-2pt)$);

  \coordinate (A2a) at ($(A)+(30:\aeRadiusA*0.65)$);
  \coordinate (B2a) at ($(B)+(140:\aeRadiusB*0.65)$);
  \coordinate (A2b) at ($(A2a)+(15pt,4pt)$);
  \coordinate (B2b) at ($(B2a)+(-4pt,3pt)$);

 \begin{scope}[rotate=280]
    \fill[red!20] (B2a) circle (4pt);
    \foreach \x in {-3,...,5}{
      \draw[blue,shorten >= rand*15] (B2a) -- (rand*\x:3);
      }      
      \fill[blue] (B2a) circle(2pt);
    \end{scope}

  \node[anchor=north west] at (A) {9-graph};
  \node                    at (B) {4-graph};
  \node                    at (C) {5-graph};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which draws some lines from circle B to spots in circle A. I am unsure how to make it so that the lines are drawn to points inside circle C. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

---

As per request, the following image is what I want [image]

and is achieved with

```
\coordinate (A1a) at ($(A)+(-20:\aeRadiusA*0.75)$);
  \coordinate (C1a) at ($(C)+(90+20:\aeRadiusC*0.75)$);
  \coordinate (A1b) at ($(A1a)+(3pt,2pt)$);
  \coordinate (C1b) at ($(C1a)+(0pt,-2pt)$);
  \coordinate (C1c) at ($(C1b)+(5pt,-2pt)$);
  \coordinate (C1d) at ($(C1c)+(10pt,8pt)$); 
  \coordinate (C1e) at ($(C1d)+(10pt,8pt)$);  
  \coordinate (C1f) at ($(C1e)+(-5pt,-2pt)$);  
  \coordinate (C1g) at ($(C1e)+(-45pt,-20pt)$);   


  \coordinate (A2a) at ($(A)+(30:\aeRadiusA*0.65)$);
  \coordinate (B2a) at ($(B)+(140:\aeRadiusB*0.65)$);
  \coordinate (A2b) at ($(A2a)+(15pt,4pt)$);
  \coordinate (B2b) at ($(B2a)+(-4pt,3pt)$);

 \begin{scope}[rotate=100]
    \fill[red!20] (B2a) circle (4pt);

    \draw[blue] (B2a) -- (C1a);
    \draw[red] (B2a)  -- (C1b);
    \draw[blue] (B2a) -- (C1c);
    \draw[red] (B2a)  -- (C1d);
    \draw[blue] (B2a) -- (C1e);
    \draw[red] (B2a)  -- (C1f);
    \draw[blue] (B2a)  -- (C1g);
    \fill[red] (B2a) circle(2pt);
 \end{scope}
```

As you can see, the lines are hard-coded and not what I want.

Comment: It would be great to add some pictures to show what you want to achieve. Additionally, please tell us what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @JFMeier See the edit

Comment: @RElon  [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ah come on what else do you need ? The code is there...

Comment: BTW, you can use \newlength{\aes} and \setlength{\aes}{0.75in} which is how 4\aes is normally implemented.

Comment: If the code is from another answer (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280501/), please acknowledge that and provide a link as it makes it much easier and is required by both courtesy and the site licensing stuff. Moreover, the code there is complete, even though the code here isn't. For example `\aeRadius*` is crucial to the fragments posted here, but only defined in the code there.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about drawing the lines from one fixed point to a number of other points with two alternating colors you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach [count=\i] \x in {a,...,g} {
        % use a mod() for swapping between red and blue
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\i, 2) ? "red" : "blue"}
        % draw from fixed point to point in foreach with color determined by mod()
        \draw [\pgfmathresult] (B2a) -- (C1\x);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```